# Trying to trigger body 'onLoad' event on jquery .load("myHTML.html")

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an html which mostly builds itself on page load, it works perfectly when I run it independently , but I need to put this html inside another html's div, I do this using ajax/jquery's .load function

i.e  `$('#myDiv').load('myHtml.html')`

but loading it this way in the div doesn't trigger the body onload event and the page is not properly build. Can you suggest how I can somehow trigger the body onload function or some other way to achieve the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place it inside `$(document).ready()`

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#myDiv').load('myHtml.html');
   });
```

Comment: I generally call a function like pageLOad()  which is called  on body 'onload()' but not only I want to call the function on load but also explicitly on a button click

Answer (score 5):

You can trigger any event manually: `$(document.body).trigger('load')`

Here's how you do it after your html is loaded:

```
$('#myDiv').load('myHtml.html', function () {
    $(document.body).trigger('load');
});
```

Comment: you would force this event as soon the request has completed, but what if myHtml.html contains a really huge jpg?

Comment: @F.Calderan how can that be a problem? Images will be loaded after that - that's what normally happen when you do onDocumentReady stuff (`$(function () { ... });`). It's enough to specify dimensions of images if you do something with positioning.

Comment: @the Answer, I don't want to trigger to onload of the parent page ,but the onload of the page which is loaded inside the div i.e myHTML

Comment: @Snedden27 There is no separate page, just a piece of HTML - you can't do that this way

Comment: but is there a way to call a function of the child(I mean myHTML) html from the parent HTML?

Comment: Of course there is a way, depending on how this function is set (global, event handler, etc)